# POST form redirecting to root

Tags: php, html, post, request

I have a login script attached below that should just add the entered value to the end of the current url and pass it to the next page. However, instead of that it is going to the root '/' and adding ?emp=. Any ideas what I have wrong?

```
<?php
/**
 * Login employee
 */

$current_page = "login.php";

require_once 'config.inc.php';
require_once 'lib.common.php';
turn_off_magic_quotes();

// Check for logout
if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
    session_stop();
    unset($_GET['emp']);            // safety
    unset($_REQUEST['empfullname']);    // safety
    // Fall through and display login form.
}

session_start();
$_SESSION['application'] = $current_page;   // security

$return_url = isset($_SESSION['login_return_url']) ? $_SESSION['login_return_url'] : '/';   
$msg        = isset($_SESSION['login_msg'])        ? $_SESSION['login_msg']        : '';    
$error_msg  = isset($_SESSION['login_error_msg'])  ? $_SESSION['login_error_msg']  : '';    
unset($_SESSION['login_msg']);          // reinitialize
unset($_SESSION['login_error_msg']);        // reinitialize

include 'setup_timeclock.php';          // authorize and initialize

// Parse arguments.
$emp        = isset($_REQUEST['emp'])       ? $_REQUEST['emp']      : null;
$empfullname    = isset($_REQUEST['empfullname'])   ? $_REQUEST['empfullname']  : null;
$password   = isset($_REQUEST['password'])      ? $_REQUEST['password']     : null;

if (! $empfullname) $empfullname = $emp;    // from url or form entry

if ($empfullname) {
    $empfullname = lookup_employee($empfullname);
    if (! $empfullname) {
        $error_msg .= "Name was not recognized. Please re-enter your name.\n";
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////
if (! $empfullname) {
    unset($_SESSION['authenticated']);

    // Get employee name

    $PAGE_TITLE = "Login - $title";
    $PAGE_STYLE = <<<End_Of_HTML
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/jquery.suggest.css" />
End_Of_HTML;

    include 'header.php';
    if ($msg) print msg($msg);
    if ($error_msg) print error_msg($error_msg);
    print <<<End_Of_HTML

<div id="employee_entry_form">
<form action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" method="get">
<table align="center" class="table_border" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th class="rightside_heading" nowrap align="left" colspan="3"><img src="../images/icons/clock_add.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Select an Employee Name:
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr><td height="15" colspan="3"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="table_rows" height="25" width="20%" style="padding-left:32px;" nowrap>Employee Name:</td>
      <td colspan="2" width="80%" style="color:red;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px;">
      <input type="text" size="25" maxlength="50" name="emp" id="emp" value="" />&nbsp;*</td></tr>
  <tr><td height="15" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="table_rows" align="right" colspan="3" style="color:red;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:10px;">*&nbsp;required&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
<table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" class="buttons">
  <tr><td width="30"><input type="image" name="submit" value="Next" align="middle" src="../images/buttons/next_button.png" /></td>
      <td><a href="index.php"><img src="../images/buttons/cancel_button.png" border="0" /></a></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>

End_Of_HTML;

    //include 'footer.php';
    exit;
}

////////////////////////////////////////

////////////////////////////////////////
// Successful login
$_SESSION['authenticated'] = $empfullname;
$return_url = preg_replace('/\bemp(fullname)?=.*?&(.*)$/','$2',$return_url);        // remove possible emp= from url
$return_url .= (preg_match('/[?]/',$return_url) ? '&' : '?') . "emp=".rawurlencode($empfullname); // add emp= argument to url
exit_next($return_url);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some standard debugging you could try, all related to your last few lines:

1. Do `$return_url` and `$empfullname` have the values you expect?  Try printing them before the regex.
2. Is the regex doing what you expect?  Hardcode some test values for `$return_url` and print the output before and after the `preg_replace` call and the `preg_match` call.
3. Is `rawurlencode` doing what you expect?  Try running it on a test value of `$empfullname` and print the result.

The problem could be anywhere in the above steps but my money's on #1.  If `$return_url` is `'/'` and  `$empfullname` is empty, then your last lines are simply appending `'?emp='` to `'/'`.

These lines could explain why `$return_url` is `'/'` and `$empfullname` is empty, if certain variables aren't set:

```
$return_url = isset($_SESSION['login_return_url']) ? $_SESSION['login_return_url'] : '/';

$empfullname    = isset($_REQUEST['empfullname'])   ? $_REQUEST['empfullname']  : null;
```